# Remove upper panel behind steering wheel on 2005 Ford E-250

Tags: ford, ignition-switch, e250

I'm trying to remove this panel behind the steering wheel, but it's lock in place by the ignition switch.

[image: steering wheel panel]

How can I do this? I tried remove the cover on the ignition switch, and to remove the entire ignition assembly, but I couldn't figure out how to do either.

Here's how it looks from below:

[image]

Comment: I'm *thinking* you need to put the key in the ignition, turn it to the on position, then press the small button on the bottom of where the cylinder is at. I'm guessing though.

Comment: Correct, put the key in and either turn to accy,or on position and depress the pin in the hole to remove the key and cylinder.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.